# Oozie output-events

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I don't understand what are the uses for the output-events in Ozzie. the Ozzie docs states that "A coordinator action can produce one or more dataset(s) instances as output", but it doesn't give any practical details or examples. what does it mean to produce a dataset instance as output? does it mean that Ozzie will create as an output a folder by the dataset's URI template? I dont really understand why should I use output evets...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Oozie, the output files are used to connecting different coordinator jobs. Consider a big DAG of coordinator jobs, some job might take other jobs' output as its input. So the datasets are the edges in the DAG.

For example, in the Oozie configuration file, if you specify Coordinator A's output is DS1, Coordinator B's output is DS2, and Coordinator C's input is DS1, and DS2, then Oozie will guarantee you that the corresponding action in Coordinator C will not be executed before DS1 and DS2 are ready.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still don't understand what is the actual use of the <output-events> node in the coordinator XML. In your example you were actually describing the need for the input-events. where is the need for output-events in your example? because even if I will not specify DS1 and DS2 in the <output-events> of coordinator A and B respectively, coordinator C will still be dependent on DS1 and DS2 anyway because they were probably stated in its input-events. so what is the practical use, and not just nominal, of the output-events node? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one use of specifying `<output-event>`s in your coordinator. When re-running a coordinator for a range of dates (using `oozie job -rerun` command), all the corresponding paths specified as `<output-event>`s will be deleted.

Sometimes it is useful to remove all the outputs generated by a coordinator's instances. For example when you want to start another coordinator that has those paths as `<input-event>`s and you want to make sure it will process the re-run data instead of the old data.